# How can I properly align contents of a div in a single line?

Tags: html, css

```css
.up, .down{
    font-size:6px;
    display:block;
    height:10px;
}
span{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rotator">
      <span><input type="text" class='Rbox' value="0" /></span>
      <span>
        <input class='up' value="&#9650;" type="button" />
        <input  class='down' value="&#9660;" type="button" />
      </span>
</div>
```

As you can see, although i was able to bring content div rotator in a single line I am still not able to give it a smooth alignment.

Comment: @Akshay I am using server controls in asp.net , it doesnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give    `vertical-align: top;`  to span will solved your issue.

Check

```css
.up,.down{
    font-size:6px;
    display:block;
height:10px;
}
span{
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="rotator">
      <span><input type="text" class='Rbox' value="0" /></span>
      <span><input class='up' value="&#9650;" type="button" />
        <input  class='down' value="&#9660;" type="button" /></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
.span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Read more at [vertical align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Answer (score 0):

Add this [vertical-align: middle;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) CSS property to the parent of the up and down class.